# Sort different elements by the same criteria

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm trying to do a sort on the following data.

```
<contents>
   <content>
      <id>
      <text>
   </content>
   <relatedcontent>
      <id>
      <text>
   </relatedcontent>
</contents>
```

This is just sample data simplified, but you get the idea. Its two different named nodes that contains the same structure.
Right now I have created two different templates to treat the content and relatedcontent separetly, but then sorting is also done separetly. Is there an easy way to sort both content and relatedcontent on ids? Lets say the `<text>` contains a text. How could I then list all the `<text>`-elements of content and relatedcontent sorted by id?

Thanks!

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a solution that is simpler, more in the spirit of XSLT and more general and flexible. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try something like this

```
<xsl:foreach select="//content | //relatedcontent">
  <xsl:sort select="id" />
  <xsl:value-of select="text" />
</xsl:foreach>
```

I guess the solution lies in the fact that you "join" `//content`  and `//relatedcontent` into a single node-set using the union operator `|`

Comment: Thanks! Im not using the foreach, im using it in a template, but that works perfect too!

Comment: It's not good to use a path with starting `//` operator when the schema is well known.

Comment: @Alejandro: As I do not know the schema well, I made a `simple` example. I think for the purpose of the answer it was good enough.

Comment: +1 for simplicity and ease of application inside of a larger template.

Answer (score 7):

**This transformation shows how this can be done**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
  <contents>
   <xsl:apply-templates>
    <xsl:sort select="id" data-type="number"/>
   </xsl:apply-templates>
  </contents>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="content">
   Content Here
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="relatedcontent">
   Relatedcontent Here
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document** (corrected to be well-formed):

```
<contents>
    <content>
        <id>3</id>
        <text/>
    </content>
    <relatedcontent>
        <id>2</id>
        <text/>
    </relatedcontent>
</contents>
```

**the wanted, correctly sorted result is produced**:

```
<contents>
   Relatedcontent Here

   Content Here
 </contents>
```

**Do note**:

1. **No use of** `<xsl:for-each>`. Only `<xsl:apply-templates>` is used.
2. **No use of the XPath union operator** (yes, it is called *the union* operator, nothing to do with pipes).
3. **If in the future a third element to be sorted on `id` is added to the XML document, this transformation will still work** without any changes.

Comment: Technically you're right. But I guess it's easier for an XSL-beginner to go with `<xsl:for-each/>` in most cases.

Comment: @Lucas-Eder: It may *feel* easier for *certain type* of beginner to use `<xsl:for-each>`. However teaching a beginer to use `<xsl:for-each>` and not showing him that `<xsl:apply-templates>` is much more powerful and universal -- this is plain wrong. Not to mention that there are other types of beginners that have no prior programming experience and such people usually learn `<xsl:apply-templates>` most naturally. Not to mention that the OP himself mentioned that he is *not* using `<xsl:for-each>`

Comment: hehe **"plain wrong"**... I like that. Is that you in this comic strip: http://xkcd.com/386/ ? ;-) Seriously, a quick grep over our large-scale web-application (600'000 users, 2'000+ concurrent sessions at any time) shows me that there are about 1263 <xsl:foreach/> loops. I guess we are what you consider a *certain type* of beginner... But there. I +1 you for your "universal" answer.

Comment: @Lukas-Eder: The size of an application generally does not correlate with the XSLT experience of its developers. I have seen *much larger* applications with a "beginner" XSLT quality, so your fact comes as no surprize. Because of these facts we are even more obliged to explain to people what XSLT really is. As for the XKCD cartoon, yes, this is a nice one that I have known for a long time. No, I am not the dude in the picture, I will not tell you how to grow turnip. I am not a "know everything" type, just good at a few things and nothing else.

Comment: Wow. Well I can live with that. No nightmares about them 1263 for-eaches... :-)